# SharePoint Office 365 Edit Item List

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, form, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list in Office 365 that is created using an app created with Power Apps.

Each item is a request sent by an user. Thus, some fields are automatically generated that are like "Created by", "Created (date)" and sequential ID, etc.

The thing is that there are some requests that I need to modify manually but when I go to the list page, I can't edit those fields, by using the quick edit view (they appear in grey). They don't appear in the edit form view. See images below:

[image: SharePoint List]

[image: SharePoint Form]

Is there any way to modify those fields on certain IDs manually?

Thanks!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The ID field is generated by SharePoint, you can't edit it but you can hide it from the view. If you want to have another type of ID to identify the item according your use case, you can add your own ID column (named anything other than ID) and use it, but you can't change the existing one as it's generated once an item is added.